# toLocaleString doesn't seem to work as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to print out a date/time in a format that the user is comfortable with. I have:

```
options = { day: "numeric", year: "numeric", month: "short", time: "short", hour12: false, hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" };
```

When the `locale` is specified explictly, `options` appear to be followed:

```
date.toLocaleString("en-US", options);
```

will produce:

> Jun 26, 2017, 13:05

If I leave out the locale parameter:

```
date.toLocaleString(options);
```

will produce:

> 6/26/2017, 1:05:00 PM

What is the locale that will be used if I leave it out? As far as I know, the locale of my PC and browser used for the test is en-US.

How do I display date/time using the browser's locale without hardcoding?

```js
var options = { day: "numeric", year: "numeric", month: "short", time: "short", hour12: false, hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" };

var D = new Date();
d = D.toLocaleString("en-US", options);
e = D.toLocaleString(options);
f = D.toLocaleString("en-US");

$("#d").text(d);
$("#e").text(e);
$("#f").text(f);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='d'></div>
<div id='e'></div>
<div id='f'></div>
```

Comment: For me in the NL with a UK setting, I get `2017-6-26 18:32:23` without locale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
opts = { day: "numeric", year: "numeric", month: "short", time: "short", hour12: false, hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit" };
date.toLocaleString(undefined, opts);
```

Taken from:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Essentially it still requires something to be passed in for that first parameter. Otherwise it ignores your options object.